# Why is this switch statement not working?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.3

I have this code

```
(1..50).each do |num|
    case num
      when num % 4 == 0, num % 6 == 0
        puts 'Cluck'
      when num % 4 == 0
        puts 'Cluck Cluck'
      when num % 5 == 0
        puts 'Cluck Cluck Cluck'
      else
        puts num
    end
end
```

For some odd reason, instead of putting cluck cluck on the fourth line or cluck on the 24th line, it's just putting a list of 1 through 100. I can't figure out what's wrong with the switch statement. The first when using the comma or && doesn't change anything either (which I don't believe it should).

Answer (score 3):

## Problems

#### case a when b

```
case a
when b
```

tests if `a` is equal to `b`.

In your case, `a` is a number (`num`) and `b` is a boolean (`num % 4 == 0`) so this never happens.

#### when b,c

Another problem is that

```
case
when b,c
```

tests if `b` **or** `c`.

If you want to check that `num` is divisible by 24, you need `b` **and** `c`.

## Solution

Remove `num` from `case` and use logical and (`&&`) :

```
(1..100).each do |num|
  case
  when num % 4 == 0 && num % 6 == 0
  ## or just :
  # when num % 24 == 0
    puts 'Cluck'
  when num % 4 == 0
    puts 'Cluck Cluck'
  when num % 5 == 0
    puts 'Cluck Cluck Cluck'
  else
    puts num
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh well, Eric's answer is right on the money. I'd just add this as a [reference](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/) -

> It doesn’t end there though you can use a case statement without giving it a value to match against, which allows a case statement to mimic the behavior of an if statement, e.g.:

```
print "Enter a string: "
some_string = gets.chomp
case
when some_string.match(/\d/)
  puts 'String has numbers'
when some_string.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)
  puts 'String has letters'
else
  puts 'String has no numbers or letters'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I read over [this guide](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/)  quick, and it seems to be that you're trying to use the `case` as an `if` statement, but you supplied a value to match against.

Because you gave `num` as the first argument of `case`, it's expecting to match against it. The problem is, your conditions evaluate to boolean values, and  `num` is a number, so they'll never match, and the else condition will always be run.

Remove the `num` from the start of the `case`.